# I want to filter the Select List. I want the drop down to only show the students which are enrolled to the same class as the class which is scheduled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an Attendance table which has a dropdown of students which is sent through a viewBag

```
ViewBag.studentID = new SelectList(db.Students, "StudentID", "Full_Name");
```

The attendance table is for a certain class (Adults, Teens or Kids) i want the students which are only enrolled in that class to show in the dropdown list

```
//Getting the scheduled classes class ID and storing it in a variable 
var ClassScheduleClassID = db.Class_Schedule.Find(id).ClassID.Value;
//checking what class the student is enrolled in and comparing it to the scheduled classes classID and storing it in a variable
var StudentClassID = db.Students
                   .Select(h => h.Enrollments
                                  .Where(m => m.ClassID == ClassScheduleClassID)
                          );
```

Then  I send the students to a dropdown list to the View via a viewBag

```
ViewBag.studentID = new SelectList(StudentClassID, "StudentID", "Full_Name");
```

It is displayed in the view like this

```
<p class="right">  
    @Html.DropDownList("studentID", null, "--Select Student--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
</p>
```

when i run it in the dropdown text i get `Systems.Collections.Generic.List'[BBM.Models.Enrollment]
I think that i passes the enrollment through instead of the students

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is actually wrong. You are selecting `Enrollments` instead of `Students`.

You need to put only `Where` for filtering in combination with `Any` like:

```
var StudentClassID = db.Students
                       .Where(h => 
                              h.Enrollments.Any(m => m.ClassID == ClassScheduleClassID));
```

Now the query says to give all those students who are enrolled i.e. have row in `Enrollments` for the ClassID which is in the variable `ClassScheduleClassID`

Comment: Thanks buddy, but i have one issue i have the first student is always showing up regardless of the class type

Comment: that is a different problem, and from above code can't say what's issue